# Rotate object consisting of multiple other rotating objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, typescript, rotation

I would like to render an object to the canvas which I rotate depending on its direction. However this object consist of multiple other objects which also should be able to rotate independently.

As far as I understand the saving and restoring of the context is the problematic part, but how do I achieve this?

```
class MotherObject {
    childObject1: ChildObject;
    childObject2: ChildObject;
    constructor(private x: number, private y: number, private direction: number, private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        this.childObject1 = new ChildObject(this.x + 50, this.y, 45, this.ctx);
        this.childObject2 = new ChildObject(this.x - 50, this.y, 135, this.ctx);
    }
    render(): void {
        this.ctx.save();
        this.ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        this.ctx.rotate(this.direction * Math.PI / 180);
        this.childObject1.render();
        this.childObject2.render();
        this.ctx.restore();
    }
}
class ChildObject {
    constructor(private x: number, private y: number, private direction: number, private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) { }
    render(): void {
        this.ctx.save();
        this.ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        this.ctx.rotate(this.direction * Math.PI / 180);
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 20);
        this.ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Does it not look correct?  Note that the order of doing rotate and translate is important, and usually I find it necessary to do in "reverse order".  It has to do with how matrix math works.

Answer (score 0):

**A complete image render function.**

The 2D API allows you to draw an image that is scaled, rotated, fade in/out. Rendering a image like this is sometimes called a sprite (From the old 16bit days)

Function to draw a scaled rotated faded image / sprite with the rotation around its center. `x` and `y` are the position on the canvas where the center will be. `scale` is 1 for no scale <1 for smaller, and >1 for larger. `rot` is the rotation with 0 being no rotation. `Math.PI` is 180 deg. Increasing rot will rotate in a clockwise direction decreasing will rotate the other way. `alpha` will set how transparent the image will be with 0 being invisible and 1 as fully visible. Trying to set global alpha with a value outside 0-1 range will result in no change. The code below does a check to ensure that alpha is clamped. If you trust the alpha value you can set `globalAlpha` directly

You can call this function without needing to restore the state as setTransform replaces the existing transformation rather than multiplying it as is done with `ctx.translate`, `ctx.scale`, `ctx.rotate`, `ctx.transform`

```
function drawSprite(image,x,y,scale,rot,alpha){
     // if you want non uniform scaling just replace the scale 
     // argument with scaleX, scaleY and use 
     // ctx.setTransform(scaleX,0,0,scaleY,x,y);
     ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,x,y);
     ctx.rotate(rot);
     ctx.globalAlpha = alpha < 0 ? 0 : alpha > 1 ? 1 : alpha; // if you may have 
                                                              // alpha values outside
                                                              // the normal range
     ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
}
// usage
drawSprite(image,x,y,1,0,1); // draws image without rotation or scale
drawSprite(image,x,y,0.5,Math.PI/2,0.5); // draws image rotated 90 deg
                                         // scaled to half its size
                                         // and semi transparent
```

The function leaves the current transform and alpha as is. If you render elsewhere (not using this function) you need to reset the current state of the 2D context.

To default

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
```

To keep the current state use

```
ctx.save();
// draw all the sprites
ctx.restore();
```